# design approach for a helper class

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I wish to design a class to have helper sort of methods on some objects. what is usually the best approach to do so. All the functions will act on these two objects.

```
SomeObj someObj;
AnotherObj anotherObj;

public SomeClass(SomeObj someObj,AnotherObj anotherObj){
this.someObj=someObj;
this.anotherObj=anotherObj;
}

somefunction(){
//act on the instance vars
}
```

or should I have simple class with no instance vars (stateless) and make function to accept the  required variables

```
public SomeClass(){

}

somefunction(SomeObj someObj,AnotherObj anotherObj){
//act on the local vars
}
```

Which approach is considered good in terms of design.

Comment: Home many functions (somefunction) do you have in helper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only method that will act on the `SomeObj` and `AnotherObj` objects is someFunction() then they probably dont need to be stored as instance vars. If they will be used/needed to modify the state of `SomeClass` from someFunction() and other internal methods, then I would say that they should indeed be stored.

You could consider a few alternatives regarding the `SomeClass` class implementation:

- If it wont have any state, then the methods should probably be static
- Depending on how complex the operations are and how many helper methods you will have, you could use a [Visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on how the "helper" methods will be used, and on how the calling class interacts with/depends on SomeObj and AnotherObj. By creating an instance of SomeClass, with internal references to SomeObj and AnotherObj, you decouple the calling class from those classes, which might be a good thing. On the other hand, if the calling class already has references to someObj and anotherObj I see no point in creating an extra object, and I'd instead go with static helper methods.